# Vários métodos num mesmo ApiController

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

Estou criando um projeto web Api e queria colocar um conjunto de métodos num mesmo ControllerApi.

Porém nos métodos, passo um objeto Json como parâmetro.
E como a estrutura deles fica parecida (vide exemplo), o controller se confunde pois acha que são todos iguais e assim chama sempre o primeiro método.

Como posso resolver isso ?

Desde já agradeço

Exemplo:

```
public class MeuController : ApiCOntroller
{
    public List<Series> ObterSeries (ParametroSeries parametros)
    { ... }

    public List<Contas> ObterContas (ParametroContas parametros)
    { ... }
}
```

A chamada está sendo feita da seguinte forma:

```
$.post("api/MeuController/ObterContas", { Identificacao: '12.234.567/0001-89' })
       .done(function (data) {  ...  })
});

$.post("api/MeuController/ObterSeries", { Identificacao: '12.234.567/0001-89' })
       .done(function (data) {  ...  })
});
```

**Obs:** Usado json pois existem outros parâmetros que podem ou não ser informados

Comment: Coloque o código onde você está passando o JSON, para vermos qual o problema.

Comment: E adicione a tag da linguagem que está usando. É so clicar em [edit] abaixo da pergunta.

Comment: Como estão as configurações de rotas no *WebApiConfig.cs*?

Comment: config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "MeuApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{parametros}"
            );

Answer (score 2):

Eu diria que o problema é mesmo as suas rotas.

Como a primeira rota que satisfazer a requisição é usada, e no seu caso a rota padrão que é usada pelo REST foi mapeada primeiro ela pode estar sendo usada, enquanto que sua API segue o estilo RPC.

Eu diria que existe duas alternativas no seu caso, primeiro se for usar apenas RPC pode remover a rota padrão, isto vai remover o suporte para REST e todo o resto deve continuar como já está.

Agora se pretende usar REST e RPC no mesmo projeto então você precisa alterar uma das rotas, por exemplo mudando o `routeTemplate` do `MeuApi` para `rpc/{controller}/{action}/{parametros}` e então fazer a mesma modificação na chamada pelo javascript, trocando o `api` por `rpc` no endereço.

Pode ser também que simplesmente alterando a ordem em que as rotas são registradas resolva o problema, mas não sei dizer com certeza se não causaria problema para o caso de uma API usando REST.

Comment: Entendi.  Vou ver certinho como vou fazer.  Muito obrigado pela ajuda pessoal !